# Changing datatype and removing commas from a number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, types

I am trying to remove commas from number which has been entered as a string and change it's data type to integer for analysis purposes

```
0      1,741,147
1          1,755
2         95,532
3        216,022
4        208,134
```

Above is the Pandas series('Active Cases') that I am working with whose data type is Object. I want to remove the commas and change the data type to int64. I have tried doing it in the following way but it is not working:

```
df['Active Cases'].replace(',','')
df['Active Cases'].astype(np.int64)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operation is not inplace, you need assign the result back

```
df['Active Cases'] = df['Active Cases'].replace(',','').astype(np.int64)
```

If you want to make the `replace` more robust, like also replace possible spaces after comma, you can do `Series.str.replace`

```py
df['Active Cases'] = df['Active Cases'].str.replace(', *', '', regex=True).astype(np.int64)
```

I would recommend do `pd.to_numeric` instead to avoid possible error

```py
df['Active Cases'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Active Cases'].str.replace(', *', '', regex=True), errors='coerce')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pandas.Series.str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) then use [pandas.Series.astype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.3/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html).

```
df['Active Cases'] = df['Active Cases'].str.replace(',', '').astype(int)
print(df['Active Cases'])
```

---

```
0    1741147
1       1755
2      95532
3     216022
4     208134
Name: Active Cases, dtype: int64
```